# How to add dotted line to a country in Africa map?

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highmaps to generate the custom/africa map but I need to make a modification which is to add dotted line in the country Morocco (and remove Western Sahara). This is a political decision... so how can I add a dotted line in the middle of a country?

Help is very much appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Could you post your code of what you  have so far please.

Answer (score 0):

In `load` event function, you can use `SVGRenderer` class to render a dotted path:

```
chart: {
    map: 'custom/africa',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var point = this.series[0].points[0];

            this.renderer.path([
                    'M', 180, 20, 'L', 210, 40, 220, 80, 300, 100
                ])
                .attr({
                    'stroke-width': 2,
                    stroke: 'red',
                    'stroke-dasharray': "5, 2"
                }).add(point.graphic.parentGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5xv8k41w/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path